# CSS issue: absolute path not working for background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, absolute-path

In a simple static webpage project, I have the following in my `main.css`:

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background: rgb(52, 73, 94);
  background: rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.7);  /* navbar-bgcolor */
  background-image: url(../../images/distant-lights.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-image: url(https://jessicasse.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/distant-lights-1-1152x8641.jpg); */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;  /* heading font */
}
```

And this works as intended. However, if I modify the background-image line and specify the absolute path `/images/distant-lights.jpg`, the image does not show up.

The project structure is as follows:

[image]

Even though the HTML+CSS works with the relative path, I would like to know why the absolute path fails. As you can see, I tried out absolute URLs with `http`, and that works just fine.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Try opening the path in dev tools and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
/images/distant-lights.jpg
```

This is not an absolute path. An absolute path starts from a system root directory. On a typical linux system it looks something like this:

```
/home/username/somefolder/someotherfolder/projectfolder/images/distant-lights.jpg
```

Comment: Ah, so HTML/CSS projects don't work with the base folder as the actual "base"? I assumed it did since the IDE autocomplete worked with this 'absolute' path, and this is how Java resources get called once the resource folder is specified. Is there a way to specify the base folder and call all paths relative to that in HTML/CSS projects?

Comment: It depends on how you're serving the webpage, since you mentioned it is a "simple static webpage project", I assumed you're not using a webserver.